# Length-1 Arrays and Python Scalars Via plt.text

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I'm trying to use plt.text to plot temperature values at their associated lat/lon points on a plot.

After reviewing the plt.text documentation, it appears that the plotted value (third arg) has to be a number and that the number has to be a whole number, NOT a number with decimals.

Below is the code that I'm trying to work with and the associated traceback error that I'm receiving:

**Script Code:**

```
data = np.loadtxt('/.../.../.../tmax_day0', delimiter=',', skiprows=1)
grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[-85:64:dx, 34:49:dx]
temp = data[:,2]
#print temp
grid_z = griddata((data[:,1],data[:,0]), data[:,2], (grid_x,grid_y), method='linear')
x,y = m(data[:,1], data[:,0]) # flip lat/lon
grid_x,grid_y = m(grid_x,grid_y)
#m.plot(x,y, 'ko', markersize=2)

def str_to_float(str):
    try:
       number = float(str)
    except ValueError:
       number = 0.0
    return number

fmt = str_to_float(temp)
#annotate point temperature on plot
plt.text(grid_x, grid_y, fmt, fontdict=None)
```

**Traceback Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "plotpoints.py", line 56, in <module>
fmt = str_to_float(temp)
File "plotpoints.py", line 51, in str_to_float
number = float(str)
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

**Data sample from text file tmax_day0:**

```
latitude,longitude,value
36.65408,-83.21783,90
41.00928,-74.73628,92.02
43.77714,-71.75598,90
44.41944,-72.01944,88.8
39.5803,-79.3394,79
38.3154,-76.5501,86
38.91444,-82.09833,94
40.64985,-75.44771,92.6
41.25389,-70.05972,81.2
39.45202,-74.56699,90.88
```

Comment: temp is uninitialised

Comment: Hi stark. I accidentally commented out temp but, the traceback error is a produced as a result of temp.

Comment: Do you want to annotate each point in `grid_x` and `grid_y` with values from `temp` ?

Comment: Yes Anand! And since they are lat/lon coordinates, each coordinate would would display the value from temp.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve plotting data values only by using the following code:

```
for i in range(len(temp)):
plt.text(x[i], y[i], temp[i], va="top", family="monospace")
```

Result:

[image: points]

Comment: Next, I need to round the two decimal place values down to only whole numbers.

Comment: You can use int() for that.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using a "proper" array, and are instead using a numpy array. Numpy arrays don't play well with non-numpy functions.

Going from your comment, this has been edited.

You would first need to fix the string so it's a proper array.

```
fmt = fmt[0].split()
```

I think should work to create a new (normal) array of strings. And then this to map that to an array of floats:

```
list_of_floats = np.array(map(float, fmt))
```

Comment: As well as the same error, "TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars"

Comment: Uhm, how does fmt look before trying to convert it? Print it to console and check...

Comment: [ 90.    92.02  90.    88.8   79.    86.    94.    92.6   81.2   90.88
  88.58  89.3   90.94  90.1   89.26  92.6   87.12  90.7   88.96  95.86
  87.82  90.    91.34  95.9 ]

Comment: No comma separation between values? Just a long string ?

Comment: Precisely, no commas.

Comment: Updated my answer, I think that will work. You need to make it into a an actual array of values first if you want to convert it into floats

Comment: Here's what I have for coding now: "fmt = temp[0].split() 

list_of_floats = np.array(map(float, fmt))

print list_of_floats

# annotate point temperature
plt.text(grid_x, grid_y, list_of_floats)"

Comment: I now have a new error: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plotpoints.py", line 49, in <module>
    fmt = temp[0].split() 
AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'split'"

Comment: That would imply you already have floats and don't need to do anything at all to the data... Ie, wouldn't need to to str_to_float() at all.

Comment: Well, thanks for all of your help and guidance. I guess I'll have to keep trying things and see if I have any luck!

Comment: run: print type(temp) and print type(temp[0]) to make sure you are correct about the types they are.

Comment: print type(temp) -> "numpy.ndarray", print type(temp[0]) -> "<type 'numpy.float64'>"